# Trying to exclude specific array entries from combobox based on variables

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I Have an array of strings in a combobox, I need to be able to have only certain ones appear based on other values from different arrays

Sorry if my explanation isn't very good, i'm not exactly sure how to word this question

```
 Public PHOSOptions() As String = {"Express portrait shoot", "Standard portrait shoot", "Deluxe portrait shoot", "Family portrait shoot", "Childrens photo shoot", "Glam Photo shoot"}
Public PHOSPrice() As Int16 = {50, 95, 175, 140, 120, 280}
Public PHOSDuration() As Int16 = {30, 60, 120, 90, 60, 240}
```

These are the three arrays I need, the first is the names that show up in the combobox, I need to only show specific ones based on if when i input certain values that relate to the the other two arrays

Example being, I Input 200 as my max price and 120 as my max duration, which then only shows me options in the combo box that are either equal or below those two in this case that being  all except for the last one

```
 ComboBox1.MaxDropDownItems = PHOSOptions.Length
    For stepper = 0 To (PHOSOptions.Length - 1)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(PHOSOptions(stepper))
    Next
```

This Is how i'm populating the combobox

Comment: Consider creating a class with 3 properties (e.g, Name, Price, Duration). It'll make your life much easier.

Comment: As with all programming problems, think of the logic first - how would you do it manually - formalise the logic into an algorithm and then only write code to explicitly implement that algorithm. One logical way to approach this would be to use a `For` loop from zero to the arrays' upper bound and, if the values in the other two arrays at the current index are within the appropriate range then add it value from the `String` array to the drop-down list.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, that is definitely how it should work in a "proper" application but there's every chance that the OP is a student and has to use concurrent arrays. Of course, if this is homework, they should have told us that. Otherwise it may appear that they are cheating by trying to get others to do their homework for them.

Comment: You may also read up on data bindings.  To me you're just making an extra complication by having an array then duplicating the array elements in the combo box items collection

Answer (score 0):

I Did Exactly as John in the comments recommended, remove the orignal way of populating the combobox, and just going through each one with a for loop to test them all

```
 Dim MaxP As Int16 = TextBox1.Text
    Dim MaxD As Int16 = TextBox2.Text
    For stepper = 0 To (PHOSPrice.Length - 1)
        If MaxP >= PHOSPrice(stepper) Then
            If MaxD >= PHOSDuration(stepper) Then
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(PHOSOptions(stepper))
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: That's a good first effort, but I have a few comments. Firstly, rather than having two nested `If` blocks, you should have one `If` statement and combine the criteria using appropriate Boolean operators.

Comment: Secondly, the fact that you are assigning `String` values to `Int16` variables demonstrates that you have `Option Strict Off`. Your class may not require it but I strongly recommend turning it `On` in the project properties and in the VS options, so it is `On` by default in future. That will force you to think more about data types and thus write better code. In that specific case, you would need to explicitly convert the `String` to an `Int16` best practice requires that you validate the input too, as a `TextBox` could contain anything and not just a number.